# How to send multiple image in telegram bot sendPhoto() method if one URL not respond

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

i'm new in python and have a problem. I want to send some photos with telegram bot with using below code.E.g.i want to send 5 image with different URL and i write below code 5 times with different URL.my problem is that when one of the URLs is wrong or not respond my code stop their for example if first URL has problem the other 4 sendPhoto doesn't run and i want my code continue and send other 4 image.anyone have any solution?

```
def start(bot, update):
 bot.sendPhoto(chat_id='chat_id', photo='URL1',caption="caption")
 bot.sendPhoto(chat_id='chat_id', photo='URL2',caption="caption")
 bot.sendPhoto(chat_id='chat_id', photo='URL3',caption="caption")
 bot.sendPhoto(chat_id='chat_id', photo='URL4',caption="caption")
 bot.sendPhoto(chat_id='chat_id', photo='URL5',caption="caption")
```

Comment: give more of your code. have you tried to catch errors?

Comment: yes i use try: except for each bot.sendPhoto but again i have same problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

one way to do so is using urllib2:

```
import urllib2
def start(bot, update):
    urls = ['url1','url2']

    for url in urls:
        ret = urllib2.urlopen(url)
        if ret.code == 200:
            bot.sendPhoto(chat_id='chat_id', photo=url,caption="caption")
```